# Create folders for uploaded files on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

As of right now, the code is uploading the files into the "something" folder.

I'm trying to make it so that each time I upload a set of files, they will all go into their own separate folder inside of the main upload folder.

I'm also trying to set up a return to show confirmation for a completed upload, but the files just simply get uploaded and nothing happens afterwards. Thanks

form.html

```
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">

    <label for="myForm">Project Database Attachment Uploader:</label>

    <br><br>


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <label for="myForm">Project Details:</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="zone" placeholder="Zone:">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="building" placeholder="Building(s):">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="propertyAddress" placeholder="Property Address:">
      </div>
      <div>

      <label for="fileText">Project Description:</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          placeholder="Describe your attachment(s) here:"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>


      <label for="attachType">Choose Attachment Type:</label>
      <br>
      <select name="attachType">
        <option value="Pictures Only">Picture(s)</option>
        <option value="Proposals Only">Proposal(s)</option>
        <option value="Pictures & Proposals">All</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Something';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var dropbox = "Something"; // Folder Name
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes to upload to a unique folder per batch. Your function 
`updateProgressbar` will be called every time a file in your batch is successfully uploaded. You have the callback parameter `idUpdate` is actually the name of the uploaded file per the server function `uploadFileToDrive`.

code.gs

```
function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName, folderName) {
 .
 .
 .
 var dropbox = folderName || "Some default Folder Name"; // Folder Name
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

Index.html

```
<script>

var numUploads = {},
numUploads.done = 0,
numUploads.total = 0,
currFolderName;

function iteratorFileUpload() {
   currFolderName = "Batch: "+new Date(); // or however you want to name the batch folder
   .
   .
   .
}



function sendFileToDrive(file) {
.
.
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolderName);
.
.
. 
}

</script
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, how would I make it so that each batch of files saves in a single folder. 

Example: BatchA goes to Folder A. 
Batch B goes to Folder B.

Right now each file is getting its own folder. Thanks

Comment: Hi Spencer I have another question, I'm trying to get all of the upload folders to go into one master folder. How would I direct it to that one with: var dropbox = folderName || "Some default Folder Name";